# How do I access object parameter passed in a function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How do I access object parameter passed in a function using javascript?
I would like to use various column_name dynamically. feature.attribute has column names. I would like to concatenate **feature.attribute** with **column name**. So far I have tried:

My code:

```
var column_name = "LOCAL_POP";

var initialize = {
    init_style: function() {
        style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style(
                    {
                        fillColor: "${getColor}",
                        strokeColor: "#00FF01",
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        graphicZIndex: 1,
                        label: "${DISTRICT}"
                    },
            {
                context: {
                    getColor: function(feature) {

**// tested by creating a local variable and window variable**

                        this.feature = feature;
                        var feature_name = 'feature.attributes.' + column_name;
                        console.log(window);
                        console.log(this['feature_name']);
                        console.log(window['feature_name']);
                        return  feature_name > 1000000 ? '#006D2C' :
                                feature_name > 100000 ? '#31A354' :
                                feature_name > 5000 ? '#74C476' :
                                feature_name >= 0 ? '#A1D99B' :
                                '';
                    }
                }
            }),
            "select": new OpenLayers.Style(
                    {
                        strokeColor: "#00FF01",
                        fillOpacity: 0.7
                    })
        });
        return style;
    }
};
```

Comment: where's the function you refer to in the question?

Comment: @BeNdErR initialize.init_style 's context function.

Comment: So are you trying to access something like `feature.attributes.randompropertyname` dynamically?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes. I am .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing your property access wrong.  To access a property of an object dynamically, use the square bracket notation without quotes (that makes it a string instead of a variable as you want):

```
feature.attributes[column_name]
```

Here's your fixed code:

```
var column_name = "LOCAL_POP";

var initialize = {
    init_style: function() {
        style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style(
                    {
                        fillColor: "${getColor}",
                        strokeColor: "#00FF01",
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        graphicZIndex: 1,
                        label: "${DISTRICT}"
                    },
            {
                context: {
                    getColor: function(feature) {

**// tested by creating a local variable and window variable**

                        this.feature = feature;
                        var feature_name = feature.attributes[column_name];
                        return  feature_name > 1000000 ? '#006D2C' :
                                feature_name > 100000 ? '#31A354' :
                                feature_name > 5000 ? '#74C476' :
                                feature_name >= 0 ? '#A1D99B' :
                                '';
                    }
                }
            }),
            "select": new OpenLayers.Style(
                    {
                        strokeColor: "#00FF01",
                        fillOpacity: 0.7
                    })
        });
        return style;
    }
};
```